# Make labels look the same in Titanium

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-alloy

In Titanium I found that the labels in the Android version have quite different amount of padding to the iOS version.

How can I normalise them so they look the same in both?

Comment: Could you add an image?

Comment: Maybe wrap the labels in a view and set different values for top, left on the labels with [platform="android"] in the .tss file